# Ignore tags with wild cards not working on iOS

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I defined `arcgis*` as one of my tags to be ignored. While this works OK on the website, I still see those questions in the iOS app. Is this expected behavior?

- App Version: 1.5.3.5
- Device: iPhone 6s
- OS Version: Version 9.3.3 (Build 13G34)

Answer (score 1):

This will be fixed in 1.6.6.2.

Highlighting and dimming was being done with simple string matching on the client side.  Now it's being done the same way as the web, splitting out ones that don't have `*` for simple matching and converting ones with `*` to regular expressions for pattern matching.